# Is it possible for customers to login with a mobile number instead of an email address?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer

I want to create new customer on this registration page and that customer assigned `mobile number` instead of `customer email`. Also remove required in the email field. I create an account for them and then assign a `mobile number`, which they then use to login, with a password.

Please share your good suggestions.

Comment: by default no. you need to customize

Comment: if you are asking that is possible, yes definitely possible. but for how to achieve that, you will need to go through deep in m2.

Comment: @Minesh My requirement also  => "Remove required in the email field on registration page"

Comment: @Abdul I am not sure it is good idea to remove the email field as required, you should have some way to communicate with users. If he remove the email, he should implement sending of sms, for forgotten password, orders info and etc.

Comment: Yes its possible, if you don't want to code, go for readymade extension
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-mobile-login.html